# What kinds of things can I predict with a naive Bayesian classifier?

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

I'm a beginner to statistics (taken only one college course), but I have a background in programming.

I just started playing with a Bayesian classifier library for Ruby and I am looking for ideas for things to analyze.

Right now I'm messing around with Tweet categorization, but do you have any ideas?

More importantly, how can I learn about which types of data lend themselves to naive Bayesian classification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), by Hastie et al. has a lot of illustrations of Machine Learning applications, and all [data sets](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/data.html) are available on the companion website, including data on spam as on the [Ruby Classifier](http://classifier.rubyforge.org/) webpage.

As for a gentle introduction to Bayes classifier, I would suggest to look at the following tutorial from Andrew Moore: [A Short Intro to Naive Bayesian Classifiers](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/naive.html) (many [other tutorials](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/) are also available).

Answer (score 1):

You can try playing with spam filtering, that's quite a common use of Naive Bayesian Classifiers.